# Find Next Closest Number in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am running PostgreSQL 9.1.9 x64 with PostGIS 2.0.3 under Windows Server 2008 R2.

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE field_data.trench_samples (
   pgid SERIAL NOT NULL,
   trench_id TEXT,
   sample_id TEXT,
   from_m INTEGER
);
```

With some data in it:

```
INSERT INTO field_data.trench_samples (
   trench_id, sample_id, from_m
)
VALUES
   ('TR01', '1000001', 0),
   ('TR01', '1000002', 5),
   ('TR01', '1000003', 10),
   ('TR01', '1000004', 15),
   ('TR02', '1000005', 0),
   ('TR02', '1000006', 3),
   ('TR02', '1000007', 9),
   ('TR02', '1000008', 14);
```

Now, what I am interested in is finding the difference (distance in metres in this example) between a record's "from_m" and the "next" "from_m" for that trench_id.

So, based on the data above, I'd like to end up with a query that produces the following table:

```
pgid, trench_id, sample_id, from_m, to_m, interval
1, 'TR01', '1000001', 0, 5, 5
2, 'TR01', '1000002', 5, 10, 5
3, 'TR01', '1000003', 10, 15, 5
4, 'TR01', '1000004', 15, 20, 5
5, 'TR02', '1000005', 0, 3, 3
6, 'TR02', '1000006', 3, 9, 6
7, 'TR02', '1000007', 9, 14, 5
8, 'TR02', '1000008', 14, 19, 5
```

Now, you are likely saying "wait, how do we infer an interval length for the last sample in each line, since there is no "next" from_m to compare to?"

For the "ends" of lines (sample_id 1000004 and 1000008) I would like to use the identical interval length of the previous two samples.

Of course, I have no idea how to tackle this in my current environment.  Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you get the difference, using the *one* previous example at the end (as shown in the data but not explained clearly in the text).

The logic here is repeated application of `lead()` and `lag()`.  First apply `lead()` to calculate the interval.  Then apply `lag()` to calculate the interval at the boundary, by using the previous interval.

The rest is basically just arithmetic:

```
select trench_id, sample_id, from_m,
       coalesce(to_m,
                from_m + lag(interval) over (partition by trench_id order by sample_id)
               ) as to_m,
       coalesce(interval, lag(interval) over (partition by trench_id order by sample_id))
from (select t.*,
             lead(from_m) over (partition by trench_id order by sample_id) as to_m,
             (lead(from_m) over (partition by trench_id order by sample_id) -
              from_m
             ) as interval
      from field_data.trench_samples t
     ) t
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/27988/2) is the SQLFiddle showing it working.

Comment: Many thanks for the quick response!  What is the reason for which you used row_number rather than just using the value stored in pgid on insert?

Comment: @Joebocop . . . No good reason at all.  I missed the `serial` when I was answering.

Comment: @Joebocop . . . The window/analytic functions are very powerful functions supported by many databases.  Glad you have the opportunity to learn about them.